# How can one tell if a company's quarterly financial report represents a profit or loss?

Tags: stock-valuation, historical-data, technical-analysis, historical-analysis

How should I review an organization's quarterly report to determine if they had a profit or loss in their last quarter?

[***Sample Report***](http://www.moneycontrol.com/livefeed_pdf/Jul2015/HOV%20Services_752.pdf)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please clarify? Are you looking to find out if a company was profitable in the last quarter? If so, please define 'profitable'. The PDF you link to shows the company had a profit based on some definitions, and a loss based on others.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, yes I want to know if company have made profit or loss so that I can manage my investment accordingly, being more specific about above PDF, I just want to know about company's financial position of last quarter (APRIL-MAY-JUNE-2015).

Comment: You need to define 'profit' and 'loss'. For example, do you wish to include 'other income', or only income from operations?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, Net profit and loss, including all other income.

Comment: Also would like to know how could I review it, what are the sections that I need to look into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined net profit to include all income and, presumably, expenses. Specifically, you are including income from other sources and are including finance costs and tax expense.

For the quarter ended June 30, 2015, the net profit, by your definition, is 12.58. This is given on line 9 of the PDF.

You ask how you can review this information. You cannot, given only the PDF you linked to. Note that the numbers have not been audited so it is the case that no trusted third party has yet reviewed it and signed off that the information is accurate.

Comment: I have a question. Do these data show that the company's report is negative (at a loss)? http://postimg.org/image/qrop99m7r/ The total expenses are larger than total net income from operations. And also, the area in the green rectangle shows that it had more losses than profit. Is this correct?

Comment: The normal income and expenses from operations do indeed result in a net loss, of 7.03. The area you outline in green shows the other income (24.11) balances out this net loss, even when considering finance costs (0) and tax expenses (4.50). By the OP's definition, this leads to a net profit of 12.58.

Comment: What about the difference in the numbers in blue and red?

Comment: The difference between the numbers in blue and red account for the loss from operations before other income and other expenses. I have no idea how the company justifies putting some income and some expenses in 'regular' categories and some in 'other' categories.